# Why did upload speed go from 10 Mbps to 0.7 Mbps?

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, upload

Currently have Comcast Xfinity setup on a new Windows 8.1 machine via wired connection. I had a decent 10 Mbps+ upload rate to begin with.

Then I installed Hamachi as well as PrivateTunnel in an effort to get a VPN set up. Uninstalled both as they were no longer needed. There were no issues with installation/uninstallation. There are no games or any other miscellaneous software on this machine.

Now, my system’s upload rate is crawling at 0.7mbps. It's only on this machine since others sharing the connection are fine.

Ran [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), [Windows Defender](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-defender), etc…  And found no issues.

Did one of these two apps do something to affect the transfer speed of this machine?

Comment: No;  My guess you actually just have an ISP problem.

Comment: @Ramhound **It's only on this machine as others are fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either Hamachi or Private Tunnel (or both) created a Network Bridge in my connections.

Makes sense I guess since my wired network connection was still bridged after both of those apps were uninstalled.

Once I removed my network from the bridge, the upload speed went back to normal.